# Core Data: Import values from old database

Tags: ios, core-data, import

I'm upgrading the current version of a dictionary app. The new version of the database has new schema and is prepopulated with new data.

However, there is a single attribute value I would like to add from the user's version of the database for about 12000 records found in 3 of the entities.

Edit: These are values that were created throughout use of the app, so I can't simply overwrite the previous database. I was hoping it was possible to load the new database, and then update certain values using data from the user's version.

How should I do this?

I need to load two versions of the dictionary with different model versions into memory and transfer across. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to perform a **core data lightweight migration**. check for a tuto on the web if required - very simple
2. You can save with your project an sqlite or xml (depend on size of data) with data to be updated  -  **OR**  - you can download from a web service of your own, the required updates.

Comment: Thanks of the response. For 1, the schema is too different. For 2. I need to get the values from the user's version of the database as they are generated during use of the app.

Comment: Do you mean I should separate all the changes for the prepopulated database and add them in after a migration to the new schema? Can I not somehow extract the attribute values I am after when the app is updated and add them in?

Comment: Are you coding an entreprise ad hoc distributed application (only limited to one company) or a consumers application ? If it is entreprise, it will be easy to manage migration in 2 steps, if it is consumers app you'll have to manage the migration in one shoot.

Comment: It's your standard iTunes iOS app. It's my mistake for not separating the user data. There is little I need from the original database. The schema has changed a lot, and most of the data (except the word itself) has changed.

Comment: you know you can do a lot and still have a lightweight migration. check the doc ! the most important things for you is : don't change the part of your model where you have the required data, then just after the migration is done, move this data to the new part of the schema and delete data from the old part.